# NotReadableError: Could not start source

Tags: javascript, cordova, getusermedia

I have added this piece of code in my project

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices = {};
}

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function (constraints) {

    var getUserMedia = (
      navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia
    );

    if (!getUserMedia) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
    });

  };
}
```

Then I'm trying to access a video stream using `getUserMedia`

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
}).then(stream => {
    // do stuff
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.name + " " + error.message);
});
```

When I test this in my emulators it works on android versions 5 and up, however when I run it on an actual device I get this error

> NotReadableError Could not start source

I have added the `cordova-plugin-media-capture` plugin to make sure my app will request the appropriate permissions, however I don't want to use the plugin I'd rather use the `getUserMedia` API.

So far my researches show that the reason for this error is that some other app is already using the camera but that's not the case, I even went a step further and restarted the device, then opened my app, making sure there are no other running apps and I still got the error.

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Yes I have the issue on ionic 2, cordova 7.

Comment: @hthetiot did you resolve it?

Comment: So far I just found that video: true, audio: false work but if I enable audio: true, I get "NotReadableError Could not start source"

Comment: Also confirm works on emulator but not on device.

Comment: Also having this issue on ionic and looking for a solution

Comment: @php_nub_qq did my answer below help?

Comment: @php_nub_qq I have updated my earlier example with a working link to a Cordova project with the steps to recreate it. Please could it be marked as the answer :)

The reason for the NotReadableError instead of the PermissionDeniedError is that your app most likely has the correct permissions in the AndroidManifiest.xml. However you are not catering for the runtime permissions from the Chrome webview. You need to cater for both to get the camera.

Comment: @Marcus sorry unfortunately I do not have time now to test this but I will accept it to honor your effort

Comment: @php_nub_qq Appreciated! Sorry it took so long for the end answer. Doing the same for Ionic now as I keep hitting this problem with my clients and my web based AR SDK's...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update - 19/11/2020**

WKWebView can use getUserMedia in iOS 14.3 beta 1.

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208667
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458

**Update - 04/06/2020**

Another bug ticket has been filed specifically for WKWebView. No support.
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208667

Updates to standalone mode gaining getUserMedia access in iOS 13.4
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185448#c6

**Update - 14/09/2019**

There are changes to Safari on iOS 13 & Safari 13: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes

SFSafariViewController has gained getUserMedia functionality (!!!, however I need to confirm this, please see below for reports of it working)

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183201

However WKWebView does not seem to gain getUserMedia functionality:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185448

iOS 13 and Safari 13 release notes:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_13_release_notes
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes

**Update - 04/11/2018 - Links to working Ionic, Cordova and Native android examples with instructions**

[GitHub link to working Cordova example](https://github.com/marcusbelcher/cordova-getUserMedia-test)

[GitHub link to working Android example](https://github.com/marcusbelcher/android-getUserMedia-test)

[GitHub link to a working Ionic example](https://github.com/marcusbelcher/ionic-getUserMedia-test)

Steps to achieve getUserMedia access on Android via the Cordova framework are:

- Follow Cordova Android install instructions ([link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html))
- Add Permissions to AndroidManifiest.xml ([link](https://github.com/marcusbelcher/cordova-getUserMedia-test/blob/master/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml))
- Save [WebRTC Adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) file to `./www/js/adapter.js` and include in `./www/index.html`
- Add `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions`
- Add plugin permission code, and the necessary getUserMedia code inside of the `./www/js/index.js` file. Make sure you use getUserMedia adapter. Please see this file as an example ([link](https://github.com/marcusbelcher/cordova-getUserMedia-test/blob/master/www/js/index.js)).

Please see the full line by line instructions with a success and error image inside the GitHub project.

---

I am not sure how much of this relates to Cordova... However I had this error when I made my own Android getUserMedia test app ([link](https://github.com/marcusbelcher/android-getUserMedia-test)). It is dependant mainly on the native app user permissions, then how the parent app creates the webviews, which version of webrtc is packaged within your app, and how you call getUserMedia.

**JavaScript side of the application:**
Rather than doing browser shim code yourself make sure you use the WebRTC adapter ([link](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter)). This removes a lot of common problems. You can see an example here ([link](https://github.com/marcusbelcher/wasm-asm-camera-webgl-test)). I also recommend looking at the WebRTC Samples here ([link](https://github.com/webrtc/samples)).

**Native side of the application:**
You will need Mic and Camera user permissions for Video and Audio. This is the main culprit. You need to make sure they have been accepted before the creation of the WebView. Thus all permission checking, popups, etc, need to happen before the creation of the WebView. If permissions are granted after you most likely need to reboot the App, etc.

When you build and deploy your application go to App Settings and manually turn on the permissions if you haven't been prompted already. Then it should work.

I wasn't able to get Video/Audio emulation working in the emulator only on the actual device. I also only encountered the NotReadableError on Android utilising a WebChromeView before permissions have been accepted. Lastly The min API version for Android is 21 (Lollipop) for this functionality as the parent application needs to allow run-time permissions via WebView onPermissionRequest ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html)).

As numerous in-app browsers (Facebook, Pinterest, etc) do not handle onPermissionRequest on Android WebRTC via a website typically doesn't work. On iOS it is guaranteed (as of April 2018) not to work as Apple have only allowed WebRTC access through the Safari only. Thus Cordova is limited to Android API 21 *if* it handles the permissions correctly.

Comment: i have been struggling with this error for two days and your answer helped a lot. It was permission issue on android device. thanks @Marcus

Comment: Same for me - been struggling with it for days. What helped most is requesting the permissions before rendering anything in the app.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to add the solution to my saga of fighting this particular error. I am using Ionic to build a WebRTC chat app, and have got this error with my native Android build. Here are the things that made all the difference.

Install Ionic's AndroidPermissions plugin...

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/android-permissions
```

Don't forget to add it to **app.module.ts** as a provider

In your component's **.ts** file...

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';

...

iosCordova = false; // I use these for easy if-else logic later
androidCordova = false; // but I want you to see how I handle the logic

constructor(private platform:Platform, private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions, etc...) {
        navigator.getUserMedia = ((<any>navigator).getUserMedia || (<any>navigator).webkitGetUserMedia || (<any>navigator).mozGetUserMedia || (<any>navigator).msGetUserMedia);
        this.iosCordova = this.platform.is('ios') && typeof cordova !== 'undefined';
        this.androidCordova = this.platform.is('android') && typeof cordova !== 'undefined';
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            if( this.androidCordova ){ // is Android Native App
                // alert("Android Native")
                androidPermissions.requestPermissions(
                [
                    androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, 
                    androidPermissions.PERMISSION.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
                    androidPermissions.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO
                ]
                ).then(()=>{
//getDevices uses Enumerate Devices and initWebRTC starts the chat connections, etc...
                    this.getDevices().then(() => this.initWebRTC())
                })
            }
       }) 
    }


ngOnInit() {
        if( !this.androidCordova ){ // is NOT Android Native App
            // alert("NOT Android Native")
            try {
                this.getDevices().then(() => this.initWebRTC())     
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Inspect your **config.xml** at **myAppName/config.xml** and add *xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"* to your widget tag and add the permissions request. I had issues trying to include them in the previously existing  tags, and just add these permissions requests right under the closing tags (creating my own second set)

```
<widget id="your.app" version="1.2.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
...
</platform> // previously existing platform name="android" closing tag
<platform name="android">
    <custom-config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    </custom-config-file>
</platform>
<platform name="ios"> // previously existing platform name="ios" opening tag
```

Now, you need to inspect your **AndroidManifest.xml** file at **myAppName/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** and look for these permissions. If they are not there, add them

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Having these permissions declared in the manifest is critical to not being ignored. Apparently Android 26 is getting strict on permissions, and you can't just ask willy-nilly for them. According to the documentation I've been reading, if you are not actually using the permission from within the code you are calling it from, your request will be dropped by the OS and the user will never see it.

Anyway, I'm very junior to all this Ionic and native device development, so if anyone has anything enlightening to add, please do so! Thanks everyone!

Comment: this pushed me in the right direction! Only needed to add more permissions for audio aswell as video but now it's working :D thanks

Comment: @Wrong As Cordova packages your website as an application it is served inside of a WKWebView/UIWebView. On iOS these views are not allowed to have getUserMedia by Apple due to security concerns. You can override these security permissions on Android but not in iOS.

If you were to build this App natively, and/or build a WebRTC plugin for iOS you can achieve the same end result in capturing the camera feed and passing it to the frontend. However this is a significant undertaking.

Comment: For android it worked. I just need myAppName/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml changes. Was not necessary config.xml changes

Comment: Your post also pointed me to the right direction, I was missing the CAMERA permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I thought it was not mandatory as it's a runtime "dangerous" permission. I should have read the doc better : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera