# Receiving webcam error when using AR.js in Cordova

Tags: augmented-reality, ar.js

I have been trying to get AR.js to work within a web application that I am creating.  I am building this application as a plugin that is subsequently loaded into a platform called BuildFire (buildfire.com).  The app should just load as a web app inside of an iframe within the actual app itself.  When I load my plugin, it comes up with an error saying:

```
Webcam Error
Name: NotReadableError
Message: Could not start video source
```

It works perfectly fine if I load the same code in a mobile browser window, but not within my web app when loaded in the context of the cordova iframe.  Is there some permissions issue that is occurring where it can't access the camera in the same way the browser allows it to?

This is happening on Android on an S8, though I suspect the hardware doesn't matter too much in this case.

Comment: If you are still looking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48993023/252627 might help.