# How to fix this error : NotReadableError: Could not start video source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement video recording but getting this error. i have 2 buttons called Front Camera ,Back Camera. On click i am calling below method. first it displays the camera correctly but while switching camera it gives me the error. Please help how to fix the problem ?

```
function StartVideoCamera(obj) {
    var id = $(obj).attr('id');
    var camNode = $(obj).attr('cammode');
    if (camNode != 'user') {
        camNode = eval('{ exact: "environment" }')
    }
    var video = document.querySelector('#video' + id);
    var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: videoHeight, height: videoWidth, facingMode: camNode 
    } };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function (mediaStream) {
        window.stream = null;
        video.srcObject = null;
        recordButton.disabled = false;
        window.stream = mediaStream;
        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
            video.play();
        };
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
         alert(err.name + ": " + err.message)
         console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
     });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NotReadableError: Could not start source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775154/notreadableerror-could-not-start-source)

Comment: This error usually occurs when either your camera is being used by some other application or you try to stream from a different camera before closing the existing camera stream. So i need to stop the stream first . Suggested codes are below

Comment: const tracks = stream.getTracks();
tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());

Comment: But how to write these codes here ?

Comment: As @santosh points out, this might happen when you try to streamm from a different camera before closing the existing camera stream.
I was using the library HTML5 QR (https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode) AND from the PC, if you paused the existing camerastream  and tried to stream from a new one, it would work well. However this wasn't the case in Android. (same browsers). Followed his comment and stopped the previous camera stream it before trying to acces a new one; works like a charm now. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You need to stop the previous mediaStreamObj before calling getUserMedia again.

This happens when your other(front/back) is already in use. You need to release the camera first.

```
stream.getTracks()
.forEach(track => track.stop());
```

Here stream is what you got from **getUserMedia**

This stops all the devices (you can check that the camera light goes off on the desktop) and (on mobile devices).